# Web API Self Hosted on windows service using OWIN , Complex Objects always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, windows-services, owin

I have Web API Project ,  it is referencing dll of database entities  , it contain API Controllers , that return complex objects

when i test the Web API using visual studio (browser) or Telerik Fiddler before hosting the API on windows service  , it is working fine and return a json of complex objects as expected .

After i create another project for windows service to self host the wep API using Owin

when i test any controller that return a complex object , it always return null while if i test any controller that return simple string , it is working fine , please help 
I don't know why same things don't work after host on windows service

here my windows service startup.cs file

```
  public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string path = assembly.Substring(0, assembly.LastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\API.dll";
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new SelfHostAssemblyResolver(path));

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

here is windows service class which inherit from service base class

```
public partial class selfHosting : ServiceBase
    {
        public string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";
        private IDisposable _server = null;


        public selfHosting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (_server != null)
            {
                _server.Dispose();
            }
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }
```

below is WebApiConfig File under another project (API)

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
```

after i check localhost:9000/api/employee

it return this line

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfEmployees xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Application.Model" i:nil="true"/>
```

Controller in web API Project

```
  public class employeeController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IRepository<employee> repository = new employeeRepository();

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<employee> Get()
        {
            return repository.GetAll();
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {

        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

if the get() method return simple string , it is working fine 
for example

```
// GET api/<controller>
            public string  Get()
            {
                return "Hello" ;
            }
```

Comment: Can you show a controller example? What do your requests look like? Have  you tried setting the content-type header to something other than default?

Comment: i update me question and adding controller example , my request using fiddler look like http://localhost:9000/api/employee/ ,  the type is GET and the header is 

User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9000
content-Type : application/json